# Как запустить скопированный сайт на Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть файлы сайта, который сделан на Wordpress. Меня попросили внести небольшие правки в html, css и js. Но я никогда не работал с Wordpress. Мне просто скинули архив со всеми файлами проекта.

Чтобы нормально внести правки мне нужно как-то запустить проект. Как это сделать?
Для локального запуска я использовал локальный сервер MAMP, сайт запустился, но отображается совсем не так как должен.

Так же есть БД на MySQL.

Как правильно запустить проект ЛОКАЛЬНО?
Понятия не имею, что со всем этим делать

Comment: Правильно - отказаться от дела в котором не компетентен и  отдать работу специалисту. А как правильно сделать миграцию см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: можете попросить коллег поставить на работающем сайте плагин для миграции, например https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/, и развернуть на своем локальном сайте.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь плагином Duplicator